# which content-type i need to select to post a form-data which contains(binary and json data) in postman?

Tags: php, laravel, postman, laravel-8, content-type

If I select `content-type: application/json` then I pass my data into a body as a `raw(application/json)` then my code works that means it's posting my data into the database, but my data is mixed means binary and `form-data`, if I use `content-type: multipart/form-data` it's showing following error. How to resolve this error?

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `books` (`name`, `image`, `price`, `title`, `quantity`, `ratings`, `author`, `description`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 1, 2021-06-30 20:40:15, 2021-06-30 20:40:15)) in file C:\Users\VICKY\Desktop\8\laravel-bookstore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 692

[image: Header section]
[image: data i am posting]

`BooksController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Books;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use App\Http\Resources\Books as BooksResource;
use App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate;

class BooksController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function DisplayBooks()
    {
        $books=Books::all();
        return User::find($books->user_id=auth()->id())->books; 
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function AddBooks(Request $request)
    {
        $book=new Books();
        $book->name=$request->input('name');
        $book->image=$request->input('image'); 
        $book->price=$request->input('price');
        $book->title=$request->input('title');
        $book->quantity=$request->input('quantity');
        $book->ratings=$request->input('ratings');
        $book->author=$request->input('author');
        $book->description=$request->input('description');
        $book->user_id = auth()->id();          
        $book->save();
        return new BooksResource($book);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function ShowBook($id)
    {
        $book=Books::findOrFail($id);
        if($book->user_id==auth()->id())
            return new BooksResource($book);
        else{
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'UnAuthorized/invalid id'], 401);
            }
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function UpdateBook(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $book=Books::findOrFail($id);
        if($book->user_id==auth()->id()){
            $book->name=$request->input('name');
            $book->image=$request->input('image'); 
            $book->price=$request->input('price');
            $book->title=$request->input('title');
            $book->quantity=$request->input('quantity');
            $book->ratings=$request->input('ratings');
            $book->author=$request->input('author');
            $book->description=$request->input('description');
            $book->save();
            return new BooksResource($book);
        }
        else
        {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => ' Book is not available ith id'], 404);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function DeleteBook($id)
    {
        $book=Books::findOrFail($id);
        if($book->user_id==auth()->id()){
            if($book->delete()){
                return response()->json(['message'=>'Deleted'],201);
            }
        }
        else{
            return response()->json([
                'error' => ' Method Not Allowed/invalid Book id'], 405);
        }
    }
}
```

`Books migration`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateBooksTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->length(50)->unique();
            $table->binary('image');
            $table->integer('price')->unsigned();
            $table->text('title');
            $table->integer('quantity')->length(2)->unsigned();
            $table->integer('ratings')->length(2)->unsigned();
            $table->string('author');
            $table->longText('description');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('books');
    }
}
```

`Books.php (model)`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Books extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'image',
        'price',
        'title',
        'quantity',
        'ratings',
        'author' ,
        'description'  
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
   
    //inverse one to many
   public function user(){
       return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
   }
}
```

Comment: all is empty and we see no code where you fill the prepared statement

Comment: Presumably your code tries to read JSON from the input rather than form data. But since you didn't show us any relevant code, we can't really tell you the issue. Please update your question

Comment: @ADyson, just now i updated please check it once

Comment: @nbk, sorry for the trouble just now i updated with the code

Comment: You don't have to give content type postman automatically generates it

Comment: @PDHide, it's not taking automatically

Comment: it will click show hidden headers

Comment: or goto  postman console to see the actual request headers that was send